# Who organised elections in the ancient Roman Republic?

Tags: ancient-rome, election

I keep researching ancient Rome for my story world: alternative history where Rome has survived till the near future.

I remember from my primary school history course (and it was my favourite course) that the Roman Republic elected many officials. And I'm now reading Wikipedia articles about Roman magistrates that say they were elected officials.

But that is it, only mentions of these officials being elected.

**Who organised elections, and how?**

I'm not currently finding any description of this. I would be grateful even for a mere hint of direction to search in.

P.S. I'm not a professional historian, as you might tell, but I love history.

Comment: The Wikipedia article on [Elections in the Roman Republic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elections_in_the_Roman_Republic) might be a good starting point. In general, [documenting preliminary research is considered to improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s) to your question](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/618/why-did-my-question-get-a-downvote/785#785).

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the outgoing magistrate organized elections for his post?